Azure ML- How to register model from blob container?
i have pre-defined model and stored in a blob storage. Now i want to register model and deploy it and enable end point within Azure ML. I used below code
from azureml.core import Model
from azureml.core import Workspace

subscription_id = 'mysub
resource_group = 'my_resource_group'
workspace_name = 'my_ws_name'

ws = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

model_path = 'my_model.joblib'

container = 'mycontainer'

model_name = 'my_model_v1'

model = Model.register(workspace=ws,
                       model_name=model_name,
                       model_path=model_path,
                       description="Test_Model",
                       tags={'area': "emotion detection"},
                       model_framework=Model.Framework.SCIKITLEARN,
                       model_framework_version='0.24.1',
                       resource_configuration=None,
                       container_registry=None,
                       properties=None,
                       sample_input_dataset=None,
                       sample_output_dataset=None,
                       datasets=None,
                       model_url=f'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{model_path}')
print("Ws object created")

but the code return below error
TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'container_registry'

Is any resolution to this or any alternative approach?

is your storage account used to store model is associated with your ml workspace or completely different storage account?

Are you restricted to use sdk v1?

As per this documentation  there is no container_registry and model_url arguments to
Model.register.
Also, it is mentioned model_path is the path on the local file system where the model assets are located so you cannot give the blob url.
All you can do is using python sdk v2 which supports the datastore path.
Create a data store in you ml workspace with the storage account your model is.

After creating, go to datastore and browse for your model file.

Then copy datastore uri.

from  azure.ai.ml  import  MLClient
from  azure.ai.ml.entities  import  Model
from  azure.ai.ml.constants  import  AssetTypes
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential

subscription_id = ""
resource_group = ""
workspace = "mljgs"

ml_client = MLClient(DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)


cloud_model = Model(
    name="model-1",
    path="azureml://subscriptions/<>/resourcegroups/<>/workspaces/mljgs/datastores/jgsblob/paths/ml_models/model.pkl",
    type=AssetTypes.CUSTOM_MODEL,
    description="Model created from cloud path.")

ml_client.models.create_or_update(cloud_model)

Output:

Check this document for more information

HI @Jayashankar, the above code works, however when i use 'Model.deploy(-- by passing all config)'   return attribute error-- 'type object 'Model' has no attribute 'deploy''..

Deploy using python sdk v2. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-deploy-model?view=azureml-api-2
